# Bootstrap glyphicons appearing on the next line instead of at the end of an input element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, newline, glyphicons

I'm trying to get glyphicons to appear at the end of my inputs, yet they always appear on the next line.

```
    <div class="form-group" id="section_blocks">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="id_blockdisplay">Select Element</label>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <input class="form-control" id="id_elementdisplay" placeholder="Element" type="text" value="Element">
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As far as I am aware (only just got into bootstrap), you use span classes for glyphicons and in this case, it should appear on the end like a little button.

The same thing happens when I try to use icons for things like validating input elements. If I try add a glyphicon at the end (not with the button style this time), the span element appears on a new line along with the glyphicon.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an [input-group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) container, like this:

```
<div class="form-group" id="section_blocks">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="id_blockdisplay">
        Select Element
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="input-group">      
            <input class="form-control" id="id_elementdisplay" placeholder="Element" type="text" value="Element">
            <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-list">  
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are some examples and additional informations on how to use them on the [Bootstrap 3 manual pages](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups).

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Last thing with that, it seems to display a pixel higher than everything else. Tried playing with that a bit with css, yet I can't quite seem to get it right. Any ideas?

Comment: @StrangeOne101 Replace the span with two spans, p.e.  `<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></span>` - this should work.